# Test a node app with multiple clients

Tags: web-services, node.js, security

I'm new to server-side programming. So this question may seems very basic. I wrote a node app and I want to test it via multiple clients. How can I run the app in my local network to give other clients an local IP that they can access the app?
I tried to listen to an IP like `192.168.10.10` but it seems node have no permission to do that.
How can I do that?
I'm on a Mac OSX

Comment: curl is always a good choice.

Comment: Have you tried heroku? It's really easy

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind additional IPs/aliases to your interface on OS X.

From the command line, assuming your interface is `en0`:

`sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.0`

`en0` will have this additional IP bound to it, and the address can be used as the source for socket connections.

Now you'll need to use a tool like `curl` (with `--interface 192.168.10.10`) that will let you specify a source IP address.